# Ubuntu Precise with Raring kernel, how to create deb? Precise or raring?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kernel, ati

I wish to build a deb package (in order to install latest AMD proprietary drivers for my troublesome gfx card), given I have `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS precise`, but with the raring kernel:`Linux 3.8.0-35-generic`, how do I do this, is it:

```
sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
```

or

```
sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/raring
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I would build it for the `precise` distribution, as that is what you are running. The kernel is just what interfaces with the hardware - to quote [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31632/what-is-the-linux-kernel-and-what-does-it-do/):

> A kernel is the lowest level of easily replaceable software that
>   interfaces with the hardware in your computer. It is responsible for
>   interfacing all of your applications that are running in “user mode”
>   down to the physical hardware, and allowing processes, known as
>   servers, to get information from each other using inter-process
>   communication (IPC).